# JDOM to parse schema

Tags: java, xsd, jdom

Is it possible to parse an XSD schema into a JDOM tree?

Or is there any other library (documentation required ;)) that could accomplish this?

Thanks,

ExtremeCoder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XSD *is* XML, so of course you can parse it into JDOM and manipulate it all you'd like.

This seems like a question that's best answered by an experimentalist - why not just try it and see?  You could have answered it for yourself in the 28 minutes that have passed since you posted your question.